# What does it mean for the first term to "give" the condition $s \leq 1/2$ and why?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

[image]

[image]

What does it mean for the first term to "give" the condition $s \leq 1/2$ and why? Also the second term "gives" $s \lt2$? I don't understand what this means at all. If someone could clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author considers under what condition for $s$ the limit of the integral for $a\to 0^+$ exists.

Now, looking at the **first term** and using $\sin \sqrt x \stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\sim}\sqrt x$ you see
$$\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{x^s}\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\sim}x^{\frac 12 -s}$$

So, convergence happens for 
$$\frac 12 -s\geq 0\Leftrightarrow s\leq \frac 12$$.

Looking at the **second term**, you see (limit comparison)
$$\int_a^b\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{x^{s+1}}dx \stackrel{a\to 0^+}{\sim} \int_a^b\frac{1}{x^{s+\frac 12}}dx$$

So, convergence happens for

$$s+\frac 12 < 1 \Leftrightarrow s<\frac 12$$

So, considering these terms while $a\to 0^+$ under the condition that they should have a finit limit, these terms **"give"** the listed conditions for $s$.

**Additional info after comments:**

The question is for which $s$ does the improper integral exists for $a\to 0^+$.

**First term:**

Since
$$\left. \frac{\sin \sqrt x}{x^s}\right|_{a}^b=\frac{\sin \sqrt b}{b^s}- \frac{\sin \sqrt a}{a^s}$$
 we are only interested in the behaviour of

$$\frac{\sin \sqrt a}{a^s}= \frac{\sin \sqrt a}{\sqrt a}\cdot\frac{\sqrt a}{a^s}$$
$$= \frac{\sin \sqrt a}{\sqrt a}\cdot a^{\frac 12 -s}\stackrel{a\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ for } s=\frac 12 \\ 0 & \text{ for } s < \frac 12 \\ +\infty & \text{ for } s > \frac 12\end{cases}$$

**Second term:**

For the integrand you have

$$\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{x^{s+1}} =\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{\sqrt x}\cdot \frac 1{x^{s+\frac 12}}$$
or $$\frac{\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{x^{s+1}}}{\frac 1{x^{s+\frac 12}}} \stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}1$$
So, according to the limit comparison test for improper integrals $\int_0^b\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{x^{s+1}}dx$ is convergent ($a\to 0^+$) iff $\int_0^b\frac{1}{x^{s+\frac 12}}dx$ is convergent.

This happens, if and only if $s+\frac 12 < 1$. Otherwise it is divergent to $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what does $\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\sim}$ mean

Comment: This means they are asymptotically equivalent when $x\to 0^+$. $f(x) \stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\sim}g(x)$ means $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= 1$.

Comment: For example: $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{\sqrt x} = 1$.

Comment: When you say "convergence happens for $1/2-s \geq 0$ ". Convergence of what? Of the limit? And what if $1/2-s \leq 0$?

Comment: I will add some to my answer. Just give me a few minutes.

Comment: @ThePoorJew : I have added some more info hoping that this clarifies all.